# AssociateTo with a variable as an argument produces error

Tags: functions, evaluation, warning-messages

The following code:

```
list=Table[<\"number"->i|>,{i,1,100}];
list[[20]]["number"]

list[[1]]
AssociateTo[list[[1]],"number"->101];
list[[1]]
```

Results in...

```
20
<|number->1|>
<|number->101|>
```

as it should. Now with the same code but using a variable I get an error:

```
list=Table[<\"number"->i|>,{i,1,100}];
list[[20]]["number"]

k=1;
list[[k]]
AssociateTo[list[[k]],"number"->101];
list[[k]]
```

results in...

```
20
<|number->1|>
AssociateTo: Part specification k is neither a machine-sized integer nor a list of machine-sized integers. 
<|number->1|>
```

What's going on here?

Comment: `<\ ` is not valid. I assume you had `<|` in the actual code you ran. Please make sure you paste the exact code you used yourself. You'd be surprised to learn how often a problem turns out to be due to a difference in what someone *runs* vs what they show here (however, in your case, it is not).

Answer (score 4):

This is because `AssociateTo` has the `HoldFirst` attribute and does not evaluate its first argument before handling it.  Even if `k=1`, it only sees `list[[k]]` and not `list[[1]]`.  After you understand the `Hold...` attributes, you will find this to be standard and logical behaviour.

The direct workaround is to substitute in the literal value of `k`:

```
With[{k=k}, AssociateTo[ list[[k]], ... ] ]
```

However, in this specific case, I suggest simply using

```
list[[k, "number"]] = 101
```

`Set` also has the `HoldFirst` attribute, but it's smarter about handling its first argument. It will do that substitution for you automatically.

Unlike `AssociateTo`, I would not call the behaviour of `Set` simple or standard.  It does complicated things in the background.  But I also think that it's much more user-friendly (especially to those who don't yet know about `Hold...` attributes).