# Problem with AssociateTo inside list

Tags: list-manipulation, warning-messages, associations

Why does

```
assocList = {<|a->1, b->2|>, <|c->1, d->2|>};
AssociateTo[assocList[[2]], c->3]
```

work,
but

```
assocList = {<|a->1, b->2|>, <|c->1, d->2|>};
ind=2; AssociateTo[assocList[[ind]], c->3]
```

raise error:

```
AssociateTo::pspec: Part specification ind is neither a machine-sized integer nor a list of machine-sized integers.
```

UPD

There is already a [similar question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/181770/associateto-with-a-variable-as-an-argument-produces-error), but my question should not be deleted (but closed) for to search by "AssociateTo, list" keywords.

Comment: Interestingly, `AssociateTo[assocList[[1 + 1]], c -> 3]` also does not work.

Comment: @RudyPotter, thanks for attention! Well, it's something strange

Comment: I'm not sure `AssociateTo[assocList[[2]], c -> 3] ` is actually "working" as it returns both parts of the list.

Comment: `AssociateTo[Evaluate[assocList[[ind]]], c -> 3]` gives an odd error as well.

Comment: This works `assocList2 = assocList[[2]]; AssociateTo[assocList2, c -> 3]` but this does not `AssociateTo[<|c -> 1, d -> 2|>, c -> 3]`  I think the first term in AssociateTo has to be the name of a variable that is changeable.

Comment: `AssociateTo[assocList[[#]], c->3]&[ind]`  (or `(x |-> AssociateTo[assocList[[x]], c->3])[ind]`) are possible workarounds?

Comment: @lesobrod There is already a [similar question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/181770/19960) on the site, which explains what is going on ... ([`HoldFirst`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldFirst.html)) and proposes some workarounds.  When searching again about `HoldFirst` you could find  this interesting [popular post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/130889/19960)  with another workaround ...  Please, be sure to search the site first before posting.

Comment: @SquareOne, yes, but I searh for "AssociateTo, list, part" keywords

Comment: @lesobrod no problem ! my advice is to search first with one-two keywords and for the most popular posts first. Hope the links were useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `With`:

```
assocList = {<|a -> 1, b -> 2|>, <|c -> 1, d -> 2|>};
With[{ind = 2}, AssociateTo[assocList[[ind]], c -> 3]]
(*{<|a -> 1, b -> 2|>, <|d -> 2, c -> 3|>}*)
```

Or use `Hold`, `ReleaseHold`, and `ReplaceAll`:

```
ReleaseHold[ReplaceAll[ind -> 2][Hold[AssociateTo[assocList[[ind]], c -> 3]]]]
(*{<|a -> 1, b -> 2|>, <|d -> 2, c -> 3|>}*)
```

Comment: Instead of explicit holding, `Unevaluated` maybe more concise: `Unevaluated[AssociateTo[assocList[[ind]], c -> 4]] /. ind -> 2`

Comment: Great, many thanks! It works even inside a loop.
But what is the magic behind this? Why `Evaluate` not work?

Comment: @lesobrod The problem is that the code first needs the part you want to replace using `Set`, so `Evaluate` doesn't work, unless you first leave it as an unevaluated expression.

Comment: @swish You're right, it's more concise what you point out.

Comment: For adding one key to an association `AssociateTo` is overkill, just use `Set` directly: `assocList[[ind, Key[c]]] = 3`